# What's the Win32 API (MFC) equivalent to SystemInformation.CaptionHeight in .NET?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I am trying to figure out the Win32 API (MFC) equivalent to SystemInformation.CaptionHeight in .NET. So far I looked at SystemParametersInfo() (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724947%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and it doesn't seem to fit the bill.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can call [`GetSystemMetrics`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724385%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with an argument of `SM_CYCAPTION`. (If you look at the code for the .Net property, that's all it does.)